# Adjusting Flutter AppBar Tool Height to mobile and web

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I am trying to adjust the appbar tool height depending on mobile or web view. I am seeking to get a larger height for web screen more than 1100 px, and a different height for mobile screens usually less than 1100 px. Would be happy to learn how to do it

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to achieve your problem's solution.

1. You can check is web and assign height to the appBar.

import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';

```
height: kIsWeb ? heightForWeb : heightForMobile
```

2)Check for height with MediaQuery

```
height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height > 1100 ? heightOfWeb : heightOfMobile
```

Comment: Nice, it has worked